# Add IPv6 support to DirectAdmin server

Tags: routing, ipv6, gateway

I just set up an new DirectAdmin, and I want to prepare it for IPv6 use.
My ISP have gave me an range of IPv6 addresses that I can use. Lets say that address is 2a01:7c8:****:1f::.

My neworkadapter user DHCP to resolves its IP-addresses. When i type `ifoncig eth0` I get the following result:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:**:**:**:ce:f3  
          inet addr:37.**.**.44  Bcast:37.**.**.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a01:7c8:****:1f::/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe87:cef3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:38941 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3779534 (3.6 MiB)  TX bytes:5089379 (4.8 MiB)
```

As you can see, I have an IPv6 address set, but I can't `ping6` an IPv6 host. I get the error: `connect: Network is unreachable`.

I decided that I needed an gateway, so I tryed to add one: `ip -6 route add default via 2a01:7c8:****::1 dev eth0` (2a01:7c8:****::1 is the gateway of my ISP).

But it trows an error: `RTNETLINK answers: No route to host`.

Does somebody know what to do, and how to solve this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because the gateway is not in your subnet. You'll need to un-obfuscate your addresses so that we can tell. It is odd that you're using the all-zeros address for your eth0. That's probably not correct.

You also should be using your distribution's methods for making these settings permanent via configuration files, rather than entering them at the command line after every boot.